# UITableView Extra Label

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

I am just beginning with Xcode and I am generating some tables. I would like to know if I can get a label here:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ZgvazSh.png]

in the detail view (where I placed red).

I've tried to just place a label in the prototype cell, but that never worked.

Comment: So, you just want to add a UILabel to a UITableviewCell?

Comment: You just drag a label and place it in tableviewcell, how come it didnt work? what did it do?

Comment: It snapped back as if it didn't want to be there. Note that I am also programatically adding new cells, so this needs to be able to repeat.

Comment: You need to set the `style` of your cell to `UITableViewCellStyleCustom` (just select _Custom_ in the _Style_ inspector using interface builder) before you can add custom subviews. From your screenshot I'm guessing you currently have it set to `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`.